# incorrect devicePixelRatio in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've been playing around with the [**device mode**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports) in Chrome to test my html5 game if it scales properly in other resolutions. 
Now when I switch back to the desktop mode, my page is somewhat shrunk. After a short investiagtion it turns out it's due to incorrect `windows.devicePixelRatio`, which is all of a sudden set to `0.3333333432674408`. Previously this value was set to `1`.

Tested the game in other browsers , all of them show correct pixel ratio. 
Tried changing the folder name and (voila) the pixel ratio is back to normal. But still when I rename the folder back, I'm getting incorrect pixel-ratio value again. 
So it has to be cached somewhere but i have no idea where exactly.

Full cleanup of all browser data didn't help. Is there anything else i could try in this case?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that either cleaning chrome temp files using CCleaner or removing GPU Cache `(C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\GPUCache)` manually fixed the issue.